# Matrix Comparison between Spiratest and Testlink Test Management Tools

Tags: testing, project-management

I've our QA division is looking into implementing either Spiratest or Testlink, depending on whichever is the better of the two. I do know that the former is paid for and the later is an opensource tool. I'd like a matrix or spreadsheet with comparisons between the two, that would help with deciding on one of the tools. I must mention that our QA department subscribes to and practices the Agile Meathodology.

Any form of assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
**TestLink Features**

This Test Management Tool is independent - you are not tied down by any proprietal solution. It help you manage your entire testing process - creating test scripts, conducting tests, tracking results, and more.
Screenshot of TestLink GUI

Accelerate and simplify test development, testing, and reporting.

- Collect and organize your test cases
- Track results and metrics associated with test execution
- Track specific information about individual tests
- Capture and report details to assist you in conducting a more thorough testing process
- Modify TestLink to fit your requirements

There is a list of main features:

- Web based (Mozilla, Firefox, IE compatible)
- Each product is tested in Test Plans according to natural testing procedures
- Users have defined roles (e.g. leader, tester, etc.)
- Test cases are organized in hierarchal structure (tree menu)
- Keywords are supported to bring more depth to test organization
- Testing could be prioritized, assigned to testers, defined milestones
- Amount of Reports and Metrics are available
- Export of documentation to HTML, MS Word and MS Excel is supported
- Reports could be mailed directly from the tool
- Localization and Internacialization (from 1.6)
- General bug tracking system (from 1.6)
- Bugzilla interface
- Mantis interface
- Requirements Coverage/Tracing

http://testlink.sourceforge.net/docs/docs/features.php

**SpiraTest General Features**

- Free upgrades and support for 1 year from date of purchase
- Unlimited requirements, releases, test cases and incidents
- Support mobile devices including iOS, Android and Windows Phone.
- Support for SQL Server 2005 or newer
- Clean and powerful user interface
- Built-in screenshot capture capability
- Full Unicode Extended Character Support
- Support for Multiple Languages. Language Files Available for English, French, German, Spanish, Czech, Hungarian, Polish, Chinese and Finnish.
- WYSIWYG Rich Text Editing
- Web Services SOAP and REST APIs to enable integration with other tools/applications
- Data import wizard that allows easy migration of existing data from MS-Excel and MS-Word.
- Project import wizard that allows easy migration of existing data from HP Mercury QualityCenter (formerly TestDirector)

https://www.inflectra.com/SpiraTest/Highlights/Features-Checklist.aspx

This maybe helpful http://www.inflectra.com/Documents/SpiraTest%20Data%20Sheet.pdf